# link error when compiling using mingw32

Tags: c, curl, mingw32

so I'm trying to compile [Craft](https://github.com/fogleman/Craft/) (an open source Minecraft clone in C) using Cmake it all goes well but when it reaches "link" section it gives me several errors about CURL. i have curl installed and it's included in windows PATH. i don't know what is wrong. I's the first time I'm trying to compile an open source software so pls be specific.

here is the snapshot:

[image]

Comment: didn't know it's this hard...  any idea?

Comment: oh for god's sake...

Answer (score 1):

The error messages you see are related to not finding libcurl to link against, not the curl binary.  It is unlikely that the search path used by the build system makes use of the windows path.  Try installing libcurl from here:

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

If you still have problems, I'd try posting on a forum dedicated to the project itself.  They would probably be able to tell you what's missing in terms of the build system getting pointed at your local copy of the curl library.